# Get the named query string within JPA

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I am trying to externalize all named queries for JPA in an orm.xml file. I would like to get the named query string in my Java program for some manipulation purposes but JPA doesnt seem to expose any method that returns the named query as a string. All I can do is `createNamedQuery` with the name of the named query.

Is there any other way around this problem to get the named query string like Hibernate exposes ? Similar to `getSession().getNamedQuery("namedQueryName");` in JPA?

Thanks,
Sonu.

Comment: What kind of "manipulation purposes?" I can't see a compelling reason to externalize the string and then manipulate it rather than just passing the name into `createNamedQuery()`. Isn't the whole point of externalizing the string to decouple the Java code from the JPQL? If you're trying to decouple the logic, performing string manipulations on it sounds rather like a code smell.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you actually need, you can always access provider-specific classes via JPA (with `unwrap()` in JPA 2.0, or with downcasting in previous versions):

```
String s = em.createNamedQuery("...")
    .unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class)
    .getQueryString();
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I was also trying to get an alternative approach. 

<code>Session session = ((Session) entityManager.getDelegate()); 
String query = session.getNamedQuery('NamedQueryName');</code>

Answer (score 4):

oh well you can use introspection to get named queries annotations like:

```
String getNamedQueryCode(Class<? extends Object> clazz, String namedQueryKey) {
    NamedQueries namedQueriesAnnotation = clazz.getAnnotation(NamedQueries.class);
    NamedQuery[] namedQueryAnnotations = namedQueriesAnnotation.value();

    String code = null;
    for (NamedQuery namedQuery : namedQueryAnnotations) {
        if (namedQuery.name().equals(namedQueryKey)) {
            code = namedQuery.query();
            break;
        }
    }

    if (code == null) {
        if (clazz.getSuperclass().getAnnotation(MappedSuperclass.class) != null) {
            code = getNamedQueryCode(clazz.getSuperclass(), namedQueryKey);
        }
    }

    //if not found
    return code;
}
```